# Code worked before once and no longer works anymore

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

So this code ran before with flying colors once. Then I closed my computer, and went to sleep when i got up however and tried to run the code I now get an error in logcat and the app crashes. I have not changed the code at all? How could this even happen?

```
public class DrawingView extends View{



    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    int randomWidth = 0;
    int randomHeight = 0;
    public static int addPoints = 0;


    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        if(random == null){
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }else {
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight, radius, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

                if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
                    //Do your things here
                        if(redColor == lastColor){

                            Intent i = new Intent(this.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
                            this.getContext().startActivity(i);

                        } else {

                            addPoints++;

                        }
                }else {

                }
        }
        return true;

}

public boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if ((((x - randomWidth)*(x - randomWidth)) + ((y - randomHeight)*(y - randomHeight))) < ((radius)*(radius))){
    return true;
  }
  return false;    
}

}
```

And here is the errors in logCat. It says that it has something to do with View? and the getParent() method. I think it might have something to do with using `this` instead of the context, but I'm not sure at all java gets very confusing to me at times.

```
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502): Process: com.Tripps.thesimplegame, PID: 2502
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Tripps.thesimplegame/com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.view.View.getParent()' on a null object reference
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.view.View.getParent()' on a null object reference
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3879)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3733)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3709)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:406)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:387)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2164)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main.onCreate(Main.java:48)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
04-21 11:48:58.287: E/AndroidRuntime(2502):     ... 10 more
```

very sorry everyone. thank you for pointing out line 48 because i did not create the object for the contentent view

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    DrawingView v;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        //LinearLayout layout1 = new LinearLayout (this);
        //FrameLayout game = new FrameLayout(this);
        DrawingView v = new DrawingView (this);

        //TextView myText = new TextView(this);

        //Button redCircle = new Button(this);



        //redCircle.setWidth(300);
        //redCircle.setText(DrawingView.addPoints);


        //layout1.addView(myText);
        //layout1.addView(redCircle); 
        //redCircle.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //game.addView(myText);
        //game.addView(v);
        //game.addView(layout1);
        setContentView(v);
        //redCircle.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        // re-starts this activity from game-view. add this.finish(); to remove from stack
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: `I have not changed the code at all? How could this even happen?` -> Probably, this did not happen. Are you sure you did not change the code?

Comment: The stack trace here is related primarily to your layout xml, and slightly to your Activity class, but not at all to the custom view class which you posted in your question.

Comment: @popovitsj - no, not really.  The NPE is not occurring in the poster's code, so standard "find the offending line" approaches do not apply.

Comment: try replacing invalidate() by postInvalidate()

Comment: @popovitsj - technically "the Android SDK" is a library, but it's a bit of a stretch.  A problem like this isn't usually with the code itself, but rather that the code has been set up to fail by the configuration - likely the layout xml.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused here `com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main.onCreate(Main.java:48)`, so you should probably include this code. And show us where line 48 is.

Comment: @popovitsj - line 48 is of course the setContentView call.  The problem is either with the content or non-existence of the layout xml *referenced* on that line, not that line of Java code itself.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Okay, I am going cease and desist now :p

Comment: You could have a point though - I could theoretically see how this might result from passing a null argument on that line of Java, assuming that wouldn't cause an error higher in the call stack than the one reported here.

Comment: i had the drawing view v commented

Comment: @popovitsj, sorry it looks you were right after all - the problem was the java code calling setContentView with a null argument.  No layout xml is apparently involved

Comment: @ChrisStratton O well, even a broken clock is right twice a day.